# Filtrar Json Utilizando C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Tenho esse script em c# que me faz recuperar um token de uma api externa para a minha na qual estou desenvolvendo. Até então, consegui recuperar sem problemas os parâmetros dessa api (o token está dentro desses parâmetros) porem eu preciso somente do token e não dos outros parâmetros q ela está me passando. Como faço para recupera/filtrar somente o token ?

Anexado abaixo está o script que desenvolvi e o que me foi retornado pela api (o que está entre as caixas vermelhas são os parametros que não preciso).

```
public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json");
        var config = builder.Build();

        var username = config.GetSection("SindiOnibus:username").Value;

        var password = config.GetSection("SindiOnibus:password").Value;

         _Url = config.GetSection("SindiOnibus:Url").Value;

         using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username), 
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password) 
            });

          HttpResponseMessage respToken = await client.PostAsync(
                _Url, formContent); 

           return await respToken.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Onde recupero o token:

```
string token = await GetToken();
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorizarion", $"Bearer {token}");
```

Retorno da Api: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
"{\r\n  \"access_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkdPTkVUIiwianRpIjoiYzA1ZjBhYTgtZWY5Yy00ZTg5LTkzZWYtMjAzNTU2Nzk0YzFkIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczNDkyMzQzLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJHT05FVCIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzLzIwMDUvMDUvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL25hbWUiOiJHT05FVCIsImV4cCI6MTU3MzQ5MjQwMywiaXNzIjoiSXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiQXVkaWVuY2UifQ.nykUMmCgN4GiDY2yuagt_mls8Qs9N8HfFD3h30M5lyc\",\r\n  \"expires\": \"2019-11-11T14:13:23.2756-03:00\",\r\n  \"usuario\": {\r\n    \"id\": **,\r\n    \"nome\": \"****\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

Comment: Você pode criar um classe com essas todas essas propriedades para pode deserializar a sua string. E depois de deserializado você pode pegar qualquer valor das propriedades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe que representa o json e deserializar ela nesta classe, ou deserializar em um objeto anônimo:

> Você vai precisar fazer referência para a biblioteca `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{\r\n  \"access_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkdPTkVUIiwianRpIjoiYzA1ZjBhYTgtZWY5Yy00ZTg5LTkzZWYtMjAzNTU2Nzk0YzFkIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczNDkyMzQzLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJHT05FVCIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzLzIwMDUvMDUvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL25hbWUiOiJHT05FVCIsImV4cCI6MTU3MzQ5MjQwMywiaXNzIjoiSXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiQXVkaWVuY2UifQ.nykUMmCgN4GiDY2yuagt_mls8Qs9N8HfFD3h30M5lyc\",\r\n  \"expires\": \"2019-11-11T14:13:23.2756-03:00\",\r\n  \"usuario\": {\r\n    \"id\": \"**\",\r\n    \"nome\": \"****\"\r\n  }\r\n}";

    var definition = new { access_token = "" };

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);

    Console.WriteLine(result.access_token);
}
```

Também é possível fazer sem uma definição do objeto anônimo:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Obs.: No campo id do usuário, falou " em volta dos *, pois dá erro na deserialização.